# Spring Batch I am reading from CSV to Oracle two tables Database , I need to check retrieved record is present in Data?

Tags: spring-batch

Spring Batch I am reading from CSV to Oracle two tables  Database , I need to check retrieved record is  present in Database ? if present then Update the record if not Insert it into database
Where would i write this logic ? ItemProcessor or ItemWriter?

while processing Spring Batch csv to db if record present then i have to do update else insert

Answer (score 0):

> if present then Update the record if not Insert it into database Where would i write this logic ? ItemProcessor or ItemWriter?

I would do it in the item processor. The processor can check the presence of the item in the database and mark it for insert or update (this could be a flag on the item).

The item writer then can check this flag and issue an insert or update accordingly. You have two options for the writer:

- Create a custom item writer (The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` provided by Spring Batch performs on a single operation).
- Use a `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` with two delegate `JdbcBatchItemWriter`s, one for insert and the other for update. That composite writer uses a `Classifier` to classify items to insert or update and delegates to the right item writer accordingly.

Comment: Shall I use JPA for Select id, Id_Type from table where Id =? and Id_Type=? in processor ,
You mean to say  i have to update some field where record is present in DB (example IsREcordPresent =Y then Update else Insert , In Processor  , Please share some code  here  it would be great help

Comment: Not in DB, just a flag on the object in memory to know if the item should be updated or inserted in the writer.